# What is the difference of extending `Function` type and not extending?

Tags: scala, inheritance, lambda, subtyping

I have a functional object like:

```
object Doubler {
  def apply(v: Int) = v*2
}
```

It works when I do `Doubler(1)`

I can also extend it with lambda type:

```
object Doubler extends (Int=>Int) {...}
```

Does it make a difference? Any reasonings behind it?

Comment: With `extends` the object can be used anywhere a `Int=>Int` is accepted (e.g. `Seq[Int](..).map(Doubler)`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that in your second version `Doubler` implements `Int => Int` and in the first version it does not.

So with the second version something like `val f: Int=>Int = Doubler` or `someList.map(Doubler)` would work, but not with the first.

Answer (score 0):

In the second version your object is a function, so you can use it everywhere where a function `Int => Int` is needed.

Extending `(Int => Int)` or `Function1[Int, Int]` is the same.